# Wrong date difference calculated using momentjs

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to calculate the number of days between two dates using `moment js`.

```js
function (value) {
    var expiration= moment(value).format('DDMMYYYY');
    var today = moment().format('DDMMYYYY');
    var dayToExpiration = moment(expiration- today).format('D[days] ,H[hours]');

    console.log(today + " : " + expiration
    console.log(dayToExpiration);
```

The result is:

```
 11102018 : 28102020  //--> 11.10.2018 : 28.10.2018
 1 days ,6 hours //why only one day??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer:

As John Madhavan-Reese stated in his answer, you have to use moment [Duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) to represent the diffecence between two moments in time.

### Issue in the code sample:

In your code you are creating a moment object from the difference between `expiration` and `today`. This value is interpreded by moment as *the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch* (see [`moment(Number)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/)), so you are creating a moment object for a random day around the 1st January 1970 (see the output of `moment(expiration- today).format()` ). The `D` token in [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) stands for Day of Month, so it gives an *"incorrect"* output.

### My suggested solution:

You can calculate difference using momentjs' [`diff()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) then you can create a duration using [`moment.duration(Number)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/).

Finally you can get your desired output using [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) plug-in (by John Madhavan-Reese :D)

Here a live sample:

```js
function getDiff(value) {
     var expiration= moment(value); // Parse input as momement object
     var today = moment(); // get now value (includes current time)
     // Calculate diff, create a duration and format it
     var dayToExpiration = moment.duration(Math.abs(today.diff(expiration))).format('D[days], H[hours]');

     console.log(today.format('DDMMYYYY') + " : " + expiration.format('DDMMYYYY'));
     console.log(dayToExpiration);
}

getDiff('2018-10-28');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/2.2.2/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Dear readers, you'll need to install `moment-duration-format` as a dependency if you want to use this solution, otherwise you will receive a TypeError!

Answer (score 1):

Because your `dayToExpiration` variable should be a `moment.Duration` object, not a string.

The difference between two datetimes is a duration, not a datetime.

Comment: `dayToExpiration` is a string in the OP code sample, not a moment object. I agree with you that difference between two datetimes should be a Duration. The OP can get the desired ouput using your (wonderful) [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) plug-in.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the correction and the kind words @VincenzoC!

Answer (score 0):

I am getting errors. this one works for me:

```
moment.duration(expiration.diff(today))._milliseconds / (1000*60*60*24));
```

Comment: Do not use [internal properties](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) like `_milliseconds`, in your case you can use [`asMilliseconds()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/milliseconds/) getter instead. As general rule note that: while this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.