# Moment.js returning 2 days if duration is 24 hours

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, momentjs

I need to have a function where the user can insert a certain timeframe (e.g. 1 week or 5 days and 12 hours). Duration from Moment.js looked the most promising.

The code below returns `2 00:00`, where 2 equals the numbers of days. This should be 1 because there are only 24 hours in there.

```
moment.utc(moment.duration(24, 'hours').as("milliseconds")).format("D HH:mm");
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrong date difference calculated using momentjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764619/wrong-date-difference-calculated-using-momentjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed with the following code and the plugin:

```
moment.duration(moment().diff(moment().subtract(1, 'days')));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting 24 hours as a millisecond offset from 1970-01-01 (Unix epoch) by calling `moment.utc(...)`. This means that your moment is holding the date `1970-01-02 00:00` and you are then printing the day part.

Answer (score 0):

If the time frames are fixed and set by yourself you could always manually put in the amount of time in milliseconds to start with. e.g. 24 hours is 86400000 milliseconds.

Comment: Not all days are 24 hours long, which is why you should add days as days, not milliseconds.

Comment: Are you trying to tell me the 24 hour day is not always 24 hours?

Comment: Yes. Where daylight saving is observed, days may be 23, 23:30, 24:30 or 25 hours long (there may be others) on the dates of transition.

Answer (score 0):

You have to format the milliseconds in moment duration not in moment. I think the below line gives your expected value.

```
 moment.duration(moment.duration(24, 'hours').as("milliseconds")).format("D HH:mm");
```

Answer : 1 00:00

Comment: Do you use a duration formatting plugin? I tried this on the momentjs playground (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LMpyWd) and I'm just getting an error: `moment.duration(...).format is not a function`. The source code doesn't show that function too: https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/duration/prototype.js (it is present on the prototype of `moment` though: https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/moment/prototype.js).

Comment: Yes, you have to use moment-duration plugin.